# what are the benefits of using *.component.scss instead of just writing it in styles.scss?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I hope im clear enough because im still a beginner with Angular2. So I'm making this simple app which I generated with angular-cli. I have now 3 components with each one of them have a *.component.scss file. But I could also just paste all the styles in the main style.scss file which will be compiled by webpack.
Is there any kind of benefit in using a *.component.scss file instead of just writing it all in styles.scss?

Comment: Order, imagine a project with 800 components. You can easily find the element you wish to change in a specific, named scss file. Searching through a messy styles.scss will take way longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles at `*.component.scss` files only affect that component.

The main `style.scss` would affect the whole application.

More at: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

If the style you want should be applied to the component only, the component style should be in `*.component.scss`.

If you, OTOH, have styles that affect multiple components or the whole app, they naturally belong to `style.scss`.